# Named pipes provider could not open connection to SQL Server 1231

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, named-pipes, linked-server

I am trying to set up a linked server and running into an issue.

On the target server I have configured a user, let's say Q. I have set the source server to connect with Q's login credentials no matter what user is logged in at Source Server.

However when I try to connect, I get the error

> "Named pipes provider : could not open a connection to SQL Server
>   [1231]."

I have tried enabling and disabling named pipes in the server configuration manager, to no avail.

Also I have seen some things saying it is a security problem. The thing is, I am able to connect from Target to Source using Q's credentials in SQL management studio just fine.

Is there something stupid I'm missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- is the firewall at the linked server on?
- check if the firewall is blocking the `named pipes` port, which usually is 445
- try telnet to the linked server via port 445

Comment: The issue turned out to be local to the source server as we were able to connect from another server. At this time it is looking more like a connectivity / routing issue / firewall problem. I am accepting this answer as it is closest to what I believe the solution is. Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Open Server Objects\Linked Servers, then Properties on your linked server. What did you enter here - maybe you are mapping some existing credentials to target credentials?

You should only check the option "Be made using this security context" and then enter Q and it's login. Also, check the "Server Type" to match the destination (Sql server)

On a side note, if the error were due to not supporting of named pipes, I thing you would get a different error, like "*error 28 Server doesn't support requested protocol*"..